# Sticky Header in recylerview

Tags: android, header, android-recyclerview, sticky

I am implementing sticky header from [this](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3614), it is showing all the data with header but headers are not sticky.

I tried using LinearLayoutManager instead of LayoutManager of library,  but still it doesn't work.

```
public class MyListAdapterTest extends SectioningAdapter
{
Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();
static final boolean USE_DEBUG_APPEARANCE = false;

private class Section
{
    String alpha;
    ArrayList<Users> usersArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
}

public class ItemViewHolder extends SectioningAdapter.ItemViewHolder
{
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
    TextView name, product, description;
    ImageView mainimg, moreimg;

    public ItemViewHolder(View itemView)
    {
        super(itemView);
        relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_layout_relative_layout);
        name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_layout_name_txt);
        product = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_layout_product_txt);
        description = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_layout_description_txt);
        mainimg = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_layout_image);
        moreimg = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_layout_moreimage);
    }
}

public class HeaderViewHolder extends SectioningAdapter.HeaderViewHolder
{
    TextView titleTextView;

    public HeaderViewHolder(View itemView)
    {
        super(itemView);
        titleTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_header_txt);
    }
}


List<Users> usersList;
ArrayList<Section> sections = new ArrayList<>();

public MyListAdapterTest()
{

}

public List<Users> getUsersList()
{
    return usersList;
}

public void setUsersList(List<Users> usersList)
{
    this.usersList = usersList;
    sections.clear();

    // sort usersList into buckets by the first letter of last name
    char alpha = 0;
    Section currentSection = null;
    for (Users users : usersList)
    {

        if (users.getContact().charAt(0) != alpha)
        {
            if (currentSection != null)
            {
                sections.add(currentSection);
            }

            currentSection = new Section();
            alpha = users.getContact().charAt(0);
            currentSection.alpha = String.valueOf(alpha);
        }

        if (currentSection != null)
        {
            currentSection.usersArrayList.add(users);
        }
    }

    sections.add(currentSection);
    notifyAllSectionsDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public int getNumberOfSections()
{
    return sections.size();
}

@Override
public int getNumberOfItemsInSection(int sectionIndex)
{
    return sections.get(sectionIndex).usersArrayList.size();
}


@Override
public boolean doesSectionHaveHeader(int sectionIndex)
{
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean doesSectionHaveFooter(int sectionIndex)
{
    return false;
}

@Override
public ItemViewHolder onCreateItemViewHolder(ViewGroup parent)
{
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_layout, parent, false);
    return new ItemViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public HeaderViewHolder onCreateHeaderViewHolder(ViewGroup parent)
{
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_header, parent, false);
    return new HeaderViewHolder(v);
}

@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
@Override
public void onBindItemViewHolder(SectioningAdapter.ItemViewHolder viewHolder, int sectionIndex, int itemIndex)
{
    Section s = sections.get(sectionIndex);
    ItemViewHolder ivh = (ItemViewHolder) viewHolder;
    Users person = s.usersArrayList.get(itemIndex);
    ivh.name.setText(person.getContact());
    ivh.product.setText(person.getContactPhone());
    ivh.description.setText(person.getSR_No() + "");
}

@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
@Override
public void onBindHeaderViewHolder(SectioningAdapter.HeaderViewHolder viewHolder, int sectionIndex)
{
    Section s = sections.get(sectionIndex);
    HeaderViewHolder hvh = (HeaderViewHolder) viewHolder;

    if (USE_DEBUG_APPEARANCE)
    {
        hvh.itemView.setBackgroundColor(0x55ffffff);
        hvh.titleTextView.setText(pad(sectionIndex * 2) + s.alpha);
    } else
    {
        hvh.titleTextView.setText(s.alpha);
    }
}


private String pad(int spaces)
{
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < spaces; i++)
    {
        b.append(' ');
    }
    return b.toString();
}
}
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know about your library, but to use a sticky layout, you have to put your X view (that you want to be header) out of recycler view too. Then monitor (listener) the scroll position or first item, and control X view there.

Comment: what do you mean by control ?

Comment: I mean change the content of X. It is very tricky to implement

Comment: If the library has its own special LayoutManager, then you should probably use that.  The LayoutManager has information about things like the position of the first visible item.  That would be necessary for rendering sticky headers.

Comment: @krislarson i am using library's layout manager, it still won't stick

Comment: @UzumakiIchigo can you direct me to any example of that implementation

Comment: @krislarson i figured out the solution, thanks for you'r time

Comment: @UzumakiIchigo i figured out the solution, thanks for you'r time

Answer (score 0):

i figured out what the problem was, i was not implementing super in onBindItemViewHolder and onBindHeaderViewHolder in my adapter, so it should be

```
@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
@Override
public void onBindItemViewHolder(SectioningAdapter.ItemViewHolder viewHolder, int sectionIndex, int itemIndex)
{
    super.onBindItemViewHolder(viewHolder, sectionIndex, itemIndex);
    Section s = sections.get(sectionIndex);
    ItemViewHolder ivh = (ItemViewHolder) viewHolder;
    Users person = s.usersArrayList.get(itemIndex);
    ivh.name.setText(person.getContact());
    ivh.product.setText(person.getContactPhone());
    ivh.description.setText(person.getSR_No() + "");
}

@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
@Override
public void onBindHeaderViewHolder(SectioningAdapter.HeaderViewHolder viewHolder, int sectionIndex)
{
    super.onBindHeaderViewHolder(viewHolder, sectionIndex);
    Section s = sections.get(sectionIndex);
    HeaderViewHolder hvh = (HeaderViewHolder) viewHolder;


    if (USE_DEBUG_APPEARANCE)
    {
        hvh.itemView.setBackgroundColor(0x55ffffff);
        hvh.titleTextView.setText(pad(sectionIndex * 2) + s.alpha);
    } else
    {
        hvh.titleTextView.setText(s.alpha);
    }
}
```